# Rails comments system with bb-code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bbcode

In my rails 4 app i want to add comments to my articles, but i want to add functional as most forum-engines do (like SMF),  and i need to add bb-code for it.

Are there any good gem for it? With rails 4 support? How then in controller i can translate [quote] to some div with some style?

Also how is it good to store html data in database?

For example if i use haml, and somebody post comment as

```
- current_user.id
```

or something similar to this, how to secure my app from "bad boys" ? Sure i can change comments system to something like: quote_parent_id, but if i have multiple quotes in one comment? so it is hard to realise, better is to store html, but to secure it somehow.

Could i do this? And how? Please give good ideas, tutorials, gem-links.

Answer (score 1):

Look into https://github.com/veger/ruby-bbcode

Since it converts to HTML and does not excecute user input as Ruby code - you'll be fairly safe. However, I havent tried the gem and its possible it introduces some XSS vulnerabilities.

Have you considered [Markdown](https://github.com/joliss/markdown-rails) as an option?

Comment: "Markdown as an option?" what do you mean? <div> etc? no - it's to bad idea )

Comment: hm, with such js:       $('#article_comment_text').val(currentVal + '[quote author="' + comment_author + '" date="' + comment_date + '"]' + comment_text + '[/quote]');
   it renders me as <p>[quote author="</p>
                    
                    <p>                      Гость</p>
                      etc

Comment: Updated question with link to Markdown. Have you tried the BBcode gem I linked?

Comment: i try, just that multiquote - problem

Comment: We have had an [issue about XSS vulnerabilities](https://github.com/veger/ruby-bbcode/issues/10) which should be fixed. If you know of other issues, please [let us know](https://github.com/veger/ruby-bbcode/issues) and we'll try to fix them!

Answer (score 0):

You should also look into https://github.com/asceth/bbcoder ( I should note I am the original author ).

In the controller, changing a string such as "[quote=user]My post of epic importance[/quote]" into a div etc is just doing:

```
# assume params[:comment] is the text you are converting
params[:comment].bbcode_to_html
```

As for storing html in a database, there is no right or wrong answer.  If you want to allow users to edit their posts later then I would lean towards not storing the html version but storing their original bbcode version.  This way when you allow them to edit you aren't having to convert html back to bbcode.

To make sure you aren't open to XSS and other attacks I recommend combining other gems like sanitize.

```
Sanitize.clean(text.to_s).bbcode_to_html
```

Some more notes:

Multiple tags and nested tags are parsed as they are seen without any additional steps required.  So a comment or post with lots of bbcode tags, multiple quotes, b tags or anything else is dealt with by just calling `bbcode_to_html` on the variable/string.

If a user tries to use haml in their post it should appear as-is.  haml shouldn't try to eval the string unless you specifically tell it to which I'm not even sure how to do that unless haml as a special filter or operator.